# Love2D how to use a string to add a texture

Tags: lua, love2d

It isnt the best title yeah but I dont know how to even summerize the problem. Im trying to "export" textures where itll be like "dirt" or something then once you enter that the texture itll be added to the screen. I already have the textures there I need to know how to use strings to add a texture. I hope that isnt too hard to read and understand.

Comment: when you say `export` and then talk about `adding to the screen`, are we talking about creating a texture file output then loading that file to display it on the screen? if not what are we exporting?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little confusing what you mean by "exporting". The following code snippet stores reusable texture images in `textures` and the textures to be drawn in `onScreen`. Note that we use the `textures` table like a key-value dictionary, while we use the `onScreen` table like an ordered list.

```
function love.load()
    textures = {} -- creates a table to store textures
    textures['dirt'] = love.graphics.newImage('dirt.png') -- adds the 'dirt' texture, with a dictionary-like key

    onScreen = {} -- creates a table to store what's drawn on screen
    onScreen[#onScreen + 1] = {'dirt', 0, 0} -- appends the 'dirt' name and coords for drawing to the list of textures being drawn
end

function love.draw()
    for ind, val in pairs(onScreen) do -- for all textures onScreen
        love.graphics.draw(textures[val[1]], val[2], val[3]) -- get the image for the texture name and draw at coords
    end
end
```